# touched and valid using reactive forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How can i use the touched and valid properties using reactive forms in angular 4. I've used in template driven forms and you can just put this `<span class="text-muted" *ngIf="!fname.valid && fname.touched"> Please enter a valid first name</span>` below the input field. I've also learned that reactive forms would be better since you have to write the logic in the component.ts. So i want it to implement in the reactive form and i'm stuck on how to use the touched and valid properties.

> html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSignIn(form)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
    </div><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

> ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSignIn(form: FormGroup){
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.loginUser(email, password)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.router.navigate(['/settings']);
        alert("Login Successful");
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        alert("Invalid Email or Password");
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Maybe this:
form.control.markAllAsTouched()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

```html
<span class="text-muted" *ngIf="!form.controls['email'].valid && 
                 form.controls['email']?.touched"> Please enter a valid first name</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use it in similar way. To get the FormControl use *get* method on FormGroup object and then *hasError*:

```js
// in your template
form.get('email').hasError('required') && form.get('email').touched
form.get('email').hasError('email') && form.get('email').touched
form.get('password').hasError('required') && form.get('password').touched
```

You can also create some nice methods/getters for that in your component.

```js
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSignIn(form)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email">
      <span class="text-muted" *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('required') && form.get('email').touched">Email is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
         <span class="text-muted" *ngIf="form.get('password').hasError('required') && form.get('password').touched">Password is required</span>
    </div><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @wawka. What's the purpose of .hasError?

Comment: @Joseph You can have multiple validators on your FormControl (in your case email has two of them). You probably want to have different error message for them. hasError allows you to check if the error is on the specific validator. valid method only tells you that one of the validation failed.